# why doesn't this parameterized sql return anything while the non parameterized one does?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to use sql parameter on one of my queries and noticed when ever i do so, it just doesn't return anything! while the none parametrized one works just fine.
Why is it ?
None parametrized one :

```
string columnCommentsQuery = string.Format("SELECT   * FROM   ::fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'user', 'dbo', 'table', '{0}', 'column', default)", table[2].ToString());

    DataTable comments = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(columnCommentsQuery, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql);
    da.Fill(comments);
    conn.Close();
```

Parametrized one:

```
string columnCommentsQuery = "SELECT   * FROM   ::fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'user', 'dbo', 'table', @tb, 'column', default)";
     DataTable comments = new DataTable();
     SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(columnCommentsQuery, conn);
     sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("tb", "'" + table[2].ToString() + "'");
     conn.Open();
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql);
     da.Fill(comments);
     conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("tb", "'" + table[2].ToString() + "'");
```

to

```
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("tb", table[2].ToString() );
```

hope this helps.